# If Stored Date is Greater Than So Many Months Then

Tags: php, mysqli

#### Problem:

If the stored date ($stored_date) (yyyy-mm-dd) is greater than some time (2 months) then do something...

#### Code I Have Tried:

```
if(strtotime($stored_date) + strtotime('+2 month') <= strtotime('now')) {
   // Do something...
} else {
   // Do something...
}
```

However, this is not working for me. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Something like this should be done via a cron/scheduled task, as it would not require user interaction to process (just a suggestion)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$date = new DateTime($stored_date);
$date->add(new DateInterval('P2M'));
$now = new DateTime();
if ($date > $now)
{

}
```

Comment: Just a side note, I edited it in my original question but, the sign should be < $now. ie. The stored time is 2 months or older. It was my fault for not making that clear, but otherwise thank you for your help. Your code worked flawlessly.

Answer (score 4):

```
if (strtotime($stored_date, '+2 month') > time())
```

Comment: I guess my answer might have been more complex then is necessary

Answer (score 1):

just for an alternative approach

```
//db stuff
$q=" SELECT * , IF( `dateField` + INTERVAL 2
MONTH > NOW( ) , 'yes', 'no' ) AS DATE_CHECK
FROM FOO";

//run query get data stuff

if($DATE_CHECK =='yes') {
   // Do something...
} else {
   // Do something...
}
```